# Multiple contract verification error

Tags: contract-deployment

I am deploying a crowdsale smart contract. I deployed it on [testnet.bscscan.com](https://testnet.bscscan.com) earlier.I had to change the name of the token , so I just changed the name and tried to verify  the crowdsale contract which automatically verified my token contract in past times, But it does not verify the token contract now. I tried to deploy a same contract of previous code. Still got the problem.

I deployed it on [ropsten.etherscan.io](https://ropsten.etherscan.io).
Sill the same problem.

I also tried to verify the contract separately but got ERR_CODE_2.

Contract address of previous token: [0x39b8d1a24dbfddc655592e6f1f55e246c79c5be2](https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x39b8d1a24dbfddc655592e6f1f55e246c79c5be2)

Crowdsale address of previous token : [0x19eeD596ECDED92C5267385A2FE06C90Dd89b0B4](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x19eed596ecded92c5267385a2fe06c90dd89b0b4)

Contract address of new token : [0x8271a0794067e1F918E17fC3aFB22988E8E41e4f](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x8271a0794067e1f918e17fc3afb22988e8e41e4f#code)

Crowdsale address of new token : [0x3D4C8A91E93886a43BeD38322091CA643A5F87D2](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x3d4c8a91e93886a43bed38322091ca643a5f87d2)

Please if anyone can help. It means a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone could tell what's the difference in the expected and actual bytecodes without going into crazy compiler-level detail. Simple changes like adding a new line in the code could result in a different bytecode. Changing comments doesn't make a difference though. You change or remove any comment (remove the line entirely, reducing the number of total lines) without it impacting the resultant bytecode.

Comment: I did not changed any line, just replaced the name.

Comment: Replacing the name is enough to change the resultant bytecode.

Comment: It depends on what you specifically did the first time you deployed the renamed contract. Maybe try re-deploying it and see if you get the same bytecode.

Comment: Other things that could affect the bytecode are compiler version and whether optimizer is enabled.